# Importing tkinter duplicates printed output

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, output

I am trying start learning Tkinter to make a small gui application, however every time I do `import tkinter` all the print statements are duplicated. The problem exists with the absolute simplest script.

I am running windows 8.1 and python 3.5, and I am writing and building the application in Sublime Text 3 with a customized build system.

It is however unlikely that ST3 has anything to do with it since the problem also exists when running the script from the command line `py -3 tkinter.py`

Here is an example of my problem. This is all of the code.

```
import tkinter
print("Hello")
```

Always outputs

```
Hello
Hello
```

But code consisting of just `print("Hello")` outputs, as expected

```
Hello
```

I am truly lost with this problem and it would be of great help if any of you could point me to the right direction

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You see two prints as your named your script `tkinter.py` so the print shows when you run it  with  `py -3 tkinter.py` and you see another as you `import` again in the script. You are not importing from the `tkinter` lib but from your own script whose name shadows the tkinter lib.
To fix, rename your script and delete any `.pyc` files in the directory

Comment: YES, ofcourse. You are right. Such an obvious mistake now as you point it out. for some reason i didn't even think about it. thanks again.

Comment: No prob, lots of people get caught out shadowing libs with their scriptnames.